# C# deserializing enums from integers

Tags: c#, .net, enums, deserialization

Is it possible to deserialize an enum from an int in c#. e.g. If I have the following class:

```
class Employee
{
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public int EmployeeTypeID { get; set;}
}
```

I can easily create this from XML

```
   <Employee>
       <Name>Joe Bloggs</Name>
       <EmployeeTypeID>1</EmployeeTypeID>
   </Employee>
```

using something like this:

```
Employee employee = (Employee)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Employee)).Deserialize(XmlReader);
```

With very little work involved, this allows me to use one generic service that I can use for all database objects by feeding a select command, connection string and a type in to and retrieve an array of objects without any need for further mapping. However I have come unstuck with enums. Supposing now instead of being an integer EmployeeType is an enum:

```
public enum EmployeeTypeEnum
{
   Admin = 1,
   Sales = 2
}
```

so my class becomes:

```
class Employee
{
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public EmployeeTypeEnum EmployeeTypeID { get; set;}
}
```

Can I use the same XML and make c# recognise that the int value of EmployeeTypeID in the xml should correspond with the int value of the enum? There are other questions similar out there, but none have a very satisfactory answer are quite old, and involve wholesale changes to code. I am hoping for a better solution...

As a possible separate note (and slightly in anticipation of some responses), is using enums for this a practise best avoided? Should I be using Key-Value pairs? I would always use Key-value pairs (or similar) if there were likely to be changes, but in this case EmployeeType is fixed and will never change.

Comment: +1 - one of those questions I come across that I can't prove much use in but look forward to seeing the answer.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506368/how-do-i-serialize-an-enum-value-as-an-int help?

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250656/deserializing-enums ?

Comment: @Bridge Yes, that did help a lot, I was to busy searching for "deserialising enums" that I missed that article.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Theoretically* (= I haven't tried it), adding the `XmlEnum` attribute to your enum values should do the trick:

```
public enum EmployeeTypeEnum 
{ 
    [XmlEnum("1")] Admin = 1, 
    [XmlEnum("2")] Sales = 2 
}
```

This tells XmlSerializer that a value of EmployeeTypeEnum.Admin is to be serialized as the string `1` *and vice-versa* (which is what you need).

Regarding your side note: I don't see using enums here as a problem. If the values in the database are integers and have a fixed meaning, enums are a good solution and, in addition, serve as a documentation to the database values.

Answer (score 4):

If you xml is in this format:

```
<Employee>
  <Name>Shiv</Name>
  <EmployeeTypeID>Sales</EmployeeTypeID>
</Employee>
```

It will work as is. If you decorate your enum with the XmlEnum attribute like so:

```
    public enum EmployeeTypeEnum
{
    [XmlEnum("1")]
    Admin = 1,
    [XmlEnum("2")]
    Sales = 2
}
```

Then you can use integer values in your xml file and they will be mapped to the enum automagically.

Personally, I prefer using enums in cases like this. Even if the items in the enum could increase over time, I prefer using enums. In fact such enums are code generated from the database, so in code you don't work with Ids (much more readable).

Answer (score 0):

In xml file, Use named constant in stead of integer value. It will work just fine.

```
<Employee>
       <Name>Joe Bloggs</Name>
       <EmployeeTypeID>Admin</EmployeeTypeID>
</Employee>
```